# How to execute Robot Framework (SELENIUM) Ride Test cases in parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, robotframework

I have written my RF testcases using reusable keywords (built using native selenium webdriver not using Selenium2Library) and It works fine on single instance for what so ever browser I run.

But, I would like to execute these testcases in parallel on

1) Same machine different browsers
2) Different machine all browsers

Does Selenium Grid have native support to Robot Framework test cases? Or have any body found an alternative?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Robot Framework has native support for Java and Selenium2 within your defined "keyword" code blocks.  All you do is use [RemoteWebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver) in  your keyword phrases instead of using WebDriver .  This requires you run a Hub and a Node for the RemoteWebDriver to refer to, of course, or you can use a Sauce Labs account.  Using [Grid and Node](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-docs/blob/master/07_Selenium_Grid.md) you can run parallel tests with very little effort.

If you don't want to use RemoteWebDriver, you can still use WebDriver locally but you need to run parallel tests using "Maven surefire with threads" or a Gradle task with --parallel-threads=3" option.  I have examples of this that you can see in my GitHub account.